# Calling ".parent" on a newly instantiated associated "child" object returns "nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

```
r = Role.new(name: 'Admin')
=> #<Role id: nil, name: "Admin">
p = r.privileges.build
=> #<Privilege id: nil, role_id: nil>
p.role
=> nil
```

`Privilege` has an instance method that depends on the related `role`'s name, and has to be called before saving `r` or `p`. Calling it after running the above code raises an `` undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass `` error.

Comment: have you saved role? bit confusing `r = Role.new(name: 'Admin')` `r.save` then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what about:

```
p = r.privileges.build(role: r)
```

To make it work you should have `:role` enabled in the attr_accessible list.